# JSP data to be downloaded to Excel sheet using ActiveQuery results in character problems

Tags: java, jsp, excel, vba

downloading data using Active query from JSP page with some parameters is leading to character problems. Special characters in the german language as for example, ö, ä, ß are printed as Ã¶, Ã¤ and ÃŸ.

Debugging the JSP page in Java shows that the result that is returned by the JSP page is correct. So the problem seems to be due to conversion within excel after download, most probably due to a unsopported charset.

I tried to convert the result string in JSP to different charsets, but the problem still persists.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thank You very much in advance!

Comment: Hard to guess when you present no source code. Is string correct in jsp but wrong in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the encoding of the page?

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF8" %>  
<html>  
  <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
  </head>
  ...
```

If you can't find a solution on the Microsoft side, I'd recommend this alternative here:
http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: No problem, glad to help. when you have a chance you can also upvote-mark the answer, ok? :)